Make Azure include exception message in logs
All my code in my aspcore app includes text in the exception, like:
throw new StrangeException(500, "Could not find user");

However in Azure portal in App Insights, the message text is getting stripped. I see plenty of info on an exception but not the text, the only thing I need:

I have set ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS to true in my environment variables to no avail. Is there a way to prevent it from stripping the error text?

So are you saying there is no exception telemetry, only request telemetry as seen in your screenshot?

I'm not sure, I set it up like this in my code:
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => { loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights(); loggingBuilder.AddConsole(); });


I am able to log Exception with throw new Exception(ex.Message);


and
throw new Exception("Could not find user");

_logger.LogInformation("Controller Information");
_logger.LogError("Error message");
try
{
     throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    throw new Exception("Could not find user");
}

My Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
});

My appsettings.json file:
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=****;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus2-3.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/;ApplicationId=****"
  }
}


AFAIK, loggingBuilder.AddConsole(); is not required to log traces to ApplicationInsights. It is used to send Console logs to LogStream.

